# How to pass an integer variable as an array index in Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've struggled with an issue that seems really silly, but I could not find a solution for it.

The following variable declaration works:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            random_number: 1,
            random_array: ['A','B','C'],
        }
    }
```

However, if I try to declare a third variable that accesses random_array, as in the two examples below, it doesn't work:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            random_number: 1,
            random_array: ['A','B','C'],
            random_var: random_array[1],
        }
    }
```

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            random_number: 1,
            random_array: ['A','B','C'],
            random_var: random_array[random_number],
        }
    }
```

I have tried referencing the arrays as `this.random_array[1]` or `this.random_array[this.random_number]`, but neither have worked.

It seems like a simple syntax issue, but I couldn't figure it out or find the solution online.

Comment: You cannot reference properties of an "under construction" object from inside the object initializer. There are ways to achieve the effect, mainly by creating "getter" functions for the dependent properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to an object within this same object. It's like doing this:

```js
const myObj = {
  firstName: 'Micheal',
  lastName: 'Scott',
  name: firstName + lastName, // these variables doesn't exist
  // or even
  name: myObj.firstName + myObj.lastName, // the myObj variable isn't created yet, you can't access it from itself
}
```

Your solution is simply to put your values inside variables before doing the `return`:

```js
data() {
  const myNumber = 1;
  const myArray = ['A','B','C'];

  return {
     random_number: myNumber,
     random_array: myArray,
     random_var: myArray[myNumber],
  }
}
```

---

Note: if you name your variable with the same name as the object attribute, you can use [*shorthand property initalizer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to shorten your code:

```js
data() {
  const random_number = 1;
  const random_array = ['A','B','C'];

  return {
     random_number, // same as doing "random_number: random_number,"
     random_array,
     random_var: random_array[random_number],
  }
}
```

---

Edit: OP want `random_var` to be reactive and update whenever `random_number` change.

For this, you want to use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      random_number: 1,
      random_array: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    random_var() {
      // Will update everytime any of the reactive variables it uses change.
      return this.random_array[this.random_number];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer clarified plenty. However, I need the values to be changleable, not constant. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You should make `random_var` a computed property, so it updates whenever `random_number` changes. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you can't access other properties of the object you are currently building. You could declare a variable in the closure scope of the data property:

```
export default {
data() {
  const random_array = ['A','B','C'];
    return {
        random_number: 1,
        random_array,
        random_var: random_array[1],
    }
}
```

But likely this is not actually what you want to do, and you may want to consider setting random_var up as a computed property (such that whenever random_number is mutated, random_var will be updated).